# Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: E0024 - DevExtreme bundle already included. See: http://js.devexpress.com/error/21_2/E0024

Tags: c#, blazor, devexpress, devextreme, xaf

**Issue:**
I created a XAF Blazor project using DevExpress v.21.1 in which Dashboard feature for asp.net core (blazor) were not available. Later, in DevExpress v.21.2, the Dashboard feature was added. After updating my project to v21.2, I tried to add Dashboard feature in my project by following the steps mentioned in https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/117449/analytics/dashboards-module?p=net5 , but when I Run my project and try to create / view a dashboard, it shows the following exception.

```
[2022-01-14T17:39:16.251Z] Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: E0024 - DevExtreme bundle already included. See:
http://js.devexpress.com/error/21_2/E0024
Error: E0024 - DevExtreme bundle already included. See:
http://js.devexpress.com/error/21_2/E0024
    at d (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:9:145831)
    at Object.Error (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:9:145347)
    at Object.36991 (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:9:29970)
    at n (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:33:1708)
    at Object.85357 (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:9:34466)
    at n (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:33:1708)
    at Object.50779 (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:9:36061)
    at n (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:33:1708)
    at Object.64178 (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:9:37600)
    at n (https://localhost:44318/_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Dashboard/dx.all.js?v=82cd2362f09e4566fecfcac9c12b89da:33:1708)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at DevExpress.DashboardBlazor.Native.DashboardJSInteropProxy.ImportScripts(Nullable`1 scriptsLoadingEvent)
   at DevExpress.DashboardBlazor.DxDashboard.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDPyJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, I found the solution.

In the file _Host.cshtml, dx.all.js was included which was creating the conflict. I removed its inclusion and everything worked well after that.